# Java: Issue in converting result of exponential values to int

Tags: java

Suppose I have a range from **0-100** & I choose a random number X say 29.

Now I increase the range to a big number say a 10-digit 1023654740.

Now I want to find the place of that X in 0-1023654740. (*so that is I belive is 29% of 1023654740*)

If I perform the calculation using `Double`, I'm getting an exponent value.

```
double range = 1023654740;
double position = 29;   // Can be any number from 0 - range
Double val = (((double) position / range) * 100);

Result: 2.8329864422842414E-6
```

But I want final result in `int`.*(dont care if the final value is rounded off or truncated)*

Any suggestions

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(position / 100.0) * range`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your calculation is wrong. According to your description, you probably want to do the following:

```
Double val = ((double)position / 100) * range;
```

Then you can get your int value (by truncation) through:

```
int intVal = val.intValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

as if your result is `Double` why you just dont do

```
val.intValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a matter of presenting the result you should have a look at:

```
String myBeautifulInteger = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(val);
```

If it is just a matter of having an integer.

```
int myInt = val.intValue();
```